# AirPlay Mirroring on iPhone 4

Tags: ios, airplay

My app uses hardware features of the phone not available on the simulator and i'd like to be able to demo the app for my client via screen sharing.  Using  [AirServer](http://www.airserverapp.com/), i can AirPlay to my Mac, but my iPhone 4 doesn't support video mirroring out of the box.  Is there any magic that would let me do this?  Since this is just for a demo, undocumented APIs are encouraged.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The official way to support external screens is simply to call

```
[UIScreen screens]
```

to get a reference to available screens including the external screen. You could grap that feed with a bit of hardware for an awesome screencast.

The process is mentioned in this thread [connecting iPad to external monitor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2798534/connecting-ipad-to-external-monitor). It works equally well on iPhone and iPod. Apples official UIScreen documentation is available [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIScreen_Class/Reference/UIScreen.html)

Comment: Good answer, but the count of [UIScreen screens] is zero since it's not connected to another display and i can't enable AirPlay mirroring.  It's that last part (enable some type of AirPlay out) that i'm hoping to do with some black magic.

Comment: I know I'm a little late to provide an answer. At the moment, only the iPhone 4S supports screen mirroring via AirPlay. To test on an iPhone 4, you can buy an HDMI adapter from Apple to connect an external display, which has the same effect in the code as @Niels Castle described.

http://store.apple.com/us/product/MD098ZM/A?fnode=MTc0MjU4NjE